# How to make a discord bot to reply to anything I send

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

When I use this code, it doesn't work. The bot on replies to stickers and pictures sent locally, but not text messages.

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '*hidden*';

const PREFIX = '';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ONLINE!');
    bot.user.setActivity("to you!", {type: "LISTENING"})
})

bot.on('message', msg => {

    let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case '':
            if (msg.author.id === "547433261953974274","428526337427374080") {
                var options = ["I know right!", "I agree.", "OMG, right?"];
                var response = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
                msg.channel.send(response).then().catch(console.error);
                }
            break;
    }
})
bot.login(token);
```

Comment: You're switcing over some text and therefor `''` does not equal to `'sometext'`, just remove the switch

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple, just put the response code in the message event directly, here is an example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '*hidden*';

const PREFIX = '';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ONLINE!');
    bot.user.setActivity("to you!", {type: "LISTENING"})
})

bot.on('message', msg => {
  let authors = ['547433261953974274', '428526337427374080']
            if (authors.includes(msg.author.id)) {
                var options = ["I know right!", "I agree.", "OMG, right?"];
                var response = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
                msg.channel.send(response).then().catch(console.error);
                }
})
bot.login(token);
```

like that it's so simple, I also made a little fix for you while checking the message author, and now if there is another ID just put it in the array `authors`

**Note:** I suggest that you start using Discord.JS V13 since V12 will be outdated and your bot will stop working once the API is no anymore supported (maybe after 3-5 months, I'm not quite sure).

Have a nice day!